# shell_exec do not run php script

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I'm trying to run a .php script from a php file (website) and for that I'm using shell_exec function.

I have php-cli installed and the file is executable, but it's still not working.
I have read a lot of tutorials, and also some questions and answers in here but I just can't make this work.

Here is the piece of code:

```
shell_exec('/usr/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/mix/2/includes/connections/stomp_con.php');
```

I tried commands like `shell_exec('pwd');` and `shell_exec('whoami');` and they all work.

I also know that in order to run two commands we should be separated by semi-colon but this is just one. I run it in the terminal and it work.

Thanks in advance for your help

EDIT:

I var_dumped the shell_exec(); and it's showing me `string(104) usr/bin/php: /opt/lampp/lib/libxml2.so.2: version LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by /usr/bin/php)` because I add `2>&1` in order to output STDERR

Answer (score 0):

You need to provides space at the end of the file.something like this:

```
shell_exec("/usr/bin/php/opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/mix/2/includes/connections/stomp_con.php ");
```

Comment: A space before the last ' ? I did it and it still doesn't work

Comment: @AndréSantos yes,i also made the same mistake,once i added the space it works perfectely for me.

Comment: So it should work for me too, but it doesn't. Thanks anyway for your help. I'll wait for more answers

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't change anything. Check my updated question, I don't know what's that (I'm still searching for it)

Comment: @AndréSantos why after this there is a space. "/usr/bin/php "?

Comment: because that's the way to run it in the terminal "php ./file" I'm just passing the full path because it also doesn't work with the relative path.

Comment: @AndréSantos so your php directory contain space:i think it should be like this:"/usr/bin/php/opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/mix/2/includes/connections/stomp_con.php"

Comment: that's not the case I'm calling php because it's telling it's a php script the directory starts in /opt